# Usage of r package esquisse

Tags: r

I already installed the package with no problem but when I opened the 'ggplot builder', the window doesn't allow me to open any dataframe. I mean, there is nothing to click on at the rigth side of  the section "Choose a data.frame". Do you know what I am doing wrong?[image]

Comment: More info about esquisse: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/esquisse/readme/README.html

Comment: The relevant portion of that picture says *"from user environment"*. This suggests that you have loaded no data into R. I believe it does not have an "upload data" functionality, it will assume you've already imported it.

Comment: @r2evans I had watched video tutorials and it works fine https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpcbIyZApwA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I had to update my RStudio version. I had have the 1.1.463 and R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22). After that the package works very well.

Answer (score 1):

The `esquisse` package *requires* that data is already available in the global environment, it does not appear to provide any mechanism for importing it interactively.

In the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpcbIyZApwA) you referenced, the reason you see data in the pulldown (at time 1:16)

[image]

is because (I'm inferring) they have already attached (loaded) the `ggplot2` package into their search path. If you compare that image of available datasetes with

```r
data(package="ggplot2")
# Data sets in package 'ggplot2':
# diamonds                             Prices of over 50,000 round cut diamonds
# economics                            US economic time series
# economics_long                       US economic time series
# faithfuld                            2d density estimate of Old Faithful data
# luv_colours                          'colors()' in Luv space
# midwest                              Midwest demographics
# mpg                                  Fuel economy data from 1999 to 2008 for 38 popular models of cars
# msleep                               An updated and expanded version of the mammals sleep dataset
# presidential                         Terms of 11 presidents from Eisenhower to Obama
# seals                                Vector field of seal movements
# txhousing                            Housing sales in TX
```

you'll see the commonalities.

So really, you are responsible for making data available in the R environment. This can be via any of the `read.*` functions, or by attaching a package that has data externally available.

In this case, try `library(ggplot2)` and then `esquisse::esquisser()`.

Comment: I had tried so, but the result is the same. Anyway, I had discovered that if I use the code "esquisse::esquisser(The name of my data frame)" I can use the df with esquisse - so the problem is solved.

Comment: But there are one more problem: the 'ggplot2 builder' window is misconfigured. For those with the same problem I opened an issue here: https://github.com/dreamRs/esquisse/issues/138